# How to get current user in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am using Rails 5.2 for my application and sidekiq for processing the background job.

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :document_jobs
end


class DocumentJob < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :document

  def self.create_document_job(document, status, details)
    document.document_jobs.create(status: status, details: details, user_id: user_id)
  end

  def self.update_document_job(document_job, status, details)
    document_job.update(status: status, details: details)
  end

end
```

I want to get the current user in Document job model to store in db.

I am calling create_document_job method in all Sidekiq workers

```
class DocumentWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(*args)
    document = Document.find_by_name("sample")
    document_job = DocumentJob.create_document_job(document, "processing", "job details")

  rescue StandardError => e
   DocumentJob.create_document_job(document_job, "failed", "job error details")
  end
end
```

I want to get the current user id when creating the document job in create_document_job method of DocumentJob Model. How can I get it and store it?

Comment: Can you look up the user by the `user_id` that you're storing on the `DocumentJob`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't access the `current_user` from Devise in the jobs. So send it as a param from where you call the job.
Also, Sidekiq is using Redis, which only holds key-value pairs. So don't pass along the user object but the user ID and then in the job you can do `@user = User.find(user_id)`

Comment: I am calling the sidekiq job from cron. I won't get current user from cron

Comment: Well then pass it along from there? Also, Sidekiq is using Redis, which only hold key-value pairs. So don't pass along the user object but the user ID and then in the job you can do `@user = User.find(user_id)` - I adapted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend passing the user_id as a parameter to the job, because, in the first place, as I see, you only need the user_id, and in the second place it is lighter than passing the full loaded object, which can be inefficient if you storing many job in a queueing DB such as Redis.

If you need to load the user object, you can still do it inside the job by calling:

```
user = User.find user_id
```

Comment: I am calling the sidekiq job from cron. I won't get current user from cron.

Comment: Exactly, the current_user returns a user object based on the session of said user. If you are calling it from a cronjob then you should use user_id. It depends on the context in which you are creating the worker, the way in which you get that user_id, in an http context it is easy, because you can call current_user.id, but if you are creating the job in a cronjob that has no way of telling which user is the owner of the document, the user relation to the document should be available in your model, i.e., creating the relation between document and users.

Comment: Another option is using something like papertrail and in that way obtaining which was the last interaction between that document and a user. I'm just trying to guess what you are trying to do there. If you give more details, maybe some other ideas could pop into mind.